# Forecasting for multiple products

Tags: r, date, time-series

I want to forecast values for multiple products (in this case product_id 1 and 2 but I actually have a few thousand products) at the same time.

```
      product_id    Date    Revenue  Value
1           1     1/10/12      in     0
2           1     1/13/12      in     1
3           1     2/14/16      in     0
4           1      3/5/16     out     0
5           1      1/5/17     out     0
6           1     3/15/17     out     0
7           2     11/1/11      in     1
8           2     3/14/15      in     2
9           2     1/15/16      in     3
10          2     3/15/17     out     0
11          2     4/11/17     out     0
12          2     5/16/17     out     0
```

If this were only one product, I would fill in the missing dates with:

```
allDates <- seq.Date(
   min(Dat$Date),
   max(Dat$Date),
   "day")
allValues <- merge(
   x=data.frame(Date=allDates),
   y=Value,
   all.x=TRUE)
```

Make the data time series:

```
time <- ts(dat$Value, start= c(2011,11), frequency=52)
```

Forecast using hybrid model:

```
 hm1 <- hybridModel(y = time, weights = "insample.errors")
 plot(forecast(hm1))
```

Is there a way that I can do this for both product ids? Or is there a cleaner method without filling in the blank dates?

```
dat <-structure(list(product_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
           Date = c("1/10/12", "1/13/12", "2/14/16", "3/5/16", "1/5/17", "3/15/17", "1/1/11", "3/14/15", "1/15/16", "3/15/17", "4/11/17", "5/16/17"),
           Revenue = c("in", "in", "in", "out", "out", "out", "in", "in", "in", "out", "out", "out"),
           Value = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
         ),
      .Names = c("product_id",  "Date", "Revenue", "Value"),
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```